# JMS - DB integration

Tags: jms

For every change in DB, I wanted to notify a JMS resource. (Both residing on different servers.) May I know the best practices, for its fulfillment.

I have come across JMS/XLA concepts in Oracle docs. But it is with-respect-to a TimesTen database, which we are not going to use here.

Thanks,

Comment: See the response to this question: [Database Trigger And JMS][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729780/database-trigger-and-jms/6748330#6748330

Answer (score 3):

You could set it up like this:

- Add an insert/update/delete trigger to each table
- From each trigger, call a Java stored procedure
- In the Java stored procedure, send a JMS message to a queue etc.